# How can I get a list of all values from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries from which I'm trying to create another list of just the values. This list looks like: `a = [{'c1': 100}, {'c2': 222}, {'c3': 333}]`

And this is more-or-less what I'm trying to do. This runs properly:

```
at = []
for elem in a:
    for i in elem:
        at.append(elem[i])
```

I'm trying to do this all in just a quick list comprehension, but am getting an error: `KeyError: 'c3'`. This is what I've been trying: `at = [elem[i] for i in elem for elem in a]`

I just want `at = [100, 222, 333]`

Comment: Hmmmm...if only there were a way to get the `values` of a dictionary...maybe in some kind of method... Nah, that's just crazy talk...

Comment: I've done that too. Maybe should've included that: `at = [elem.values() for elem in a]` but that's giving me `at = [dict_values([100]), dict_values([222]), dict_values([333])]`

Comment: will the embedded dictionaries ever have more than one key? If so, what should happen?

Comment: Good question, yeah these dictionaries should only have one key. They're a result set from a SQL query and coming in as this list of dictionaries.

Comment: also, _must_ the answer use a list comprehension, or can other types of one-liners work?

Comment: I guess other options work, but I also would rather not have to use other libraries/dependencies. Mike Muller's answer gets the job done

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) along with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*[item.values() for item in a]))
[100, 222, 333]
```

OR, with *nested list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> [val for item in a for val in item.values()]
[100, 222, 333]
```

---

OR, you may use `list.extend` along with simple `for` loop (*as an alternative, although I know you requested for list comprehension*) as:

```
new_list = []
for item in a:
    new_list.extend(item.values())

# Final value hold by `new_list` will be:
# [100, 222, 333]
```

Comment: perhaps a generator expression would be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You need to swap the order of your looping so that it can be evaluated.

```
at = [elem[i] for elem in a for i in elem]
=> None
at
=> [100, 222, 333]
```

Answer (score 3):

What about just concatenating or `chain`ing all `dict.values`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [{'c1': 100}, {'c2': 222}, {'c3': 333}]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(dict.values, a)))
[100, 222, 333]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> res = []
>>> for x in a:
        res.extend(x.values())
>>> res
[100, 222, 333]
```

If there is only one value, this will work:

```
>>> [list(x.values())[0] for x in a]
[100, 222, 333]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
at = []
for elem in a:
    at += elem.values()
```

The `dict.values()` returns a list with all the values from the `dict`. For your case it will return, for each element, a list with a single component, so you just have to concatenate  it with the `at` list.